# C operators and evaluation

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=3,val;
val=sizeof (f(i))+ +f(i=1)+ +f(i-1);
printf("%d%d",val,i);
getch();
return 0;

}
int f(int num)
{
return num*5;
}
```

The compiler compiles the program and gives the output 7 1 ..what do the " + +" mean???

Answer (score 2):

First note that `sizeof` is compile-time evaluable so the first term in `val` will be `sizeof(int)`: `int` being the return type of `f`.

The value of the entire expression that you want to assign to `val` is *undefined* since `+` as a binary and unary operator is not sequenced. In essence you don't know if `i = 1` will happen before or after the evaluation of `i - 1`.

As for your specifics, `a + + b` is evaluated as `a + (+b)`. `+b` is simply a unary plus (*almost* a no-op, but does do some subtle type coercion), the other `+` is the addition operator taking two arguments.